# Change wordpress pagination method

Tags: wordpress

My current pagination method is like this: `site.com/page/2/`. But I want to change it to query like this: `site.com/?page=2`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [paginate_link function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/paginate_links/) and set the format to `?paged=%#%`. Check the link, there are some good examples.